# Why does location.replace in a .then function does not allow me to send data to firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have some functions in an even listener function (click event). Inside of it, I have a function that sends data to firestore when the 'place order' button is clicked. I have a .then function that alerts the user with 'your order has been placed' after the data is sent to firestore. This works great, but when I add another .then function after the alert function to switch to another page once the alert window is closed, the data never gets sent to firestore.

```js
var placeOrderButton = document.getElementsByClassName('placeOrderBtn')
 for (var i = 0; i < placeOrderButton.length; i++) {
     var button = placeOrderButton[i]
     button.addEventListener('click', placeOrderClicked)
 }



 function placeOrderClicked(event) {
     var y = year.getFullYear();
     var m = month.getMonth();
     var d = day.getDate();
     var h = hours.getHours();
     var m = minutes.getMinutes();
     var s = seconds.getSeconds();
     var mm = milliseconds.getMilliseconds();

     var orderID = ("" + y + m + d + h + m + s + mm);

     localStorage.setItem('processedOrderID', orderID);


     //getting and sending data to order 
     db.collection('shoppingSession').doc(localStorage.getItem('seshID')).collection('inCart').get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
         querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {


             var idName = doc.id;
             var title = doc.data().title;
             var qty = Number(doc.data().qty);
             var price = Number(doc.data().price);
             var itemTotal = qty * price;
             var orderTotal = 90.00;
             var thiss = orderTotal.toFixed(2);

             addingPrices.push(itemTotal);

             //moving data to orders table for cooks
             db.collection('orders').doc(orderID).collection('inCart').add({
                 title: title,
                 price: price,
                 qty: qty
             });

         });

     }).then(function () {
         alert("Processing your order...");


     }).then(function () {
         location.assign("index.html");
     });

     // remember that this inside an onclick event

 }; //end of onlick event
```

Comment: The problem is likely that you are not returning a promise from the first `then()` that contains the `querySnapshot.forEach`

Comment: I have added a promise with a resolve return. Still no luck.

Comment: New findings: the code that I have provided works when the url is something like "https..google...". So it is really weird that it does not work with a local file. It also works setting a timer on it.